# How to precompile assets with activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku, activeadmin

I have these lines in my production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = true    
config.assets.precompile += ['active_admin.js', 'active_admin.css', 'active_admin/print.css']
```

and my application.rb file has this line

```
config.assets.precompile = %w(*)
```

but when I try to update my assets with

```
git rm -rf public/assets
rake assets:precompile
```

I get this error

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'global-reset'
```

I have this in my Gemfile

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

What is wrong what I need to do so that I can update my assets on heroku.

Comment: Can you try by removing it from application.rb and add it in all environment as required?

Comment: Also where are you trying to precompile? Is environment parameter is missing in command?

Comment: I want to precompile in development environment and the commit public assets

Comment: can you please paste your first comment in answer it solved my problem I will mark it as accepted answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try by removing it from application.rb and add it in all environment as required?